# FedAuth cookie does not display expiry date in Firebug

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I have an ASP.Net MVC site secured with SSL and am using `System.IdentityModel.Services` and am creating the token like this:

```
SessionSecurityToken token = new SessionSecurityToken(myClaimsPrincipal, TimeSpan.FromDays(1));
SessionAuthenticationModule sam = FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule;
sam.WriteSessionTokenToCookie(token);
```

When I access the site in the browser, Firebug does not display the expiry date as expected.  Instead the expiry date is shown as **Session**:

[image: Expiry date = "Session"]

Can anyone explain why this is please?  I assume that ASP.Net can still *see* the actual expiry date internally when it reads the cookie?  More so, where is the cookie expiration time actually set?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're mixing two different things here:

- **Token Expiration** is determining until when the token is valid. After that time, even if the token is attached to a request, it is considered invalid and will not be honored. Usually the expiration time is encrypted within the token itself and that means that it's controlled solely by the token issuer.
- **Cookie Expiration** is something that is controlled by the client (your Web-Browser in this case). Once the Cookie is expired it is no longer being attached to the request. But, should the Browser decide to send it, it will work until the Token expiration has reached.

In your particular case, the Token expiration is set to 1 day, but since the Cookie expiration is set to 'Session' it means that if you were to end the session (typically by closing your Browser window) at some point before the Token expires, the Cookie will not be sent and you'll be required to login again.

After 1 day (when the Token expires), even if you're still in session, you're always required to login again.

**Update (as per your comments):**

Ticket expiration and Cookie expiration can be set separately simply because sometimes the ticket is not necessarily contained in a Cookie. It may be sent to the server using other methods (QueryString, custom HTTP header etc). Yet, indeed the natural thing to do is have them both set to the same expiration time.

This is also the case in your `SessionSecurityToken`, if you'll set its `IsPersistent` flag to `true` you'll notice that Cookie expiration is now the same as the Ticket:

```
SessionSecurityToken token = new SessionSecurityToken(myClaimsPrincipal, TimeSpan.FromDays(1));
token.IsPersistent = true;
```

Comment: Okay great, thanks.  If I want the user to not have to log in again for one day (regardless whether the browser is closed), do I need to set the cookie **and** token expiry to both be 1 day?  I assumed that the token issuer would have done this automatically given the related nature of them both?

Comment: Can you provide any detail on *why* the two are not linked automatically - e.g. the cookie persists with the token?  Surely if a token is written to a cookie, then that cookie should persist with the token timespan automatically as only the two objects combined provide a valid ClaimsIdentity?